# Organizing an array of points in python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I need to input 3, 3D points as a matrix into this function; so I made a tuple like this one:

```
initPoints = ([10,20,30],[5,15,25],[100,150,200])
```

but I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The same thing happened when i used a list. any ideas? what is 'shape'? do i need some other kind of array? How can I do that?
Thanks

Edit - the function I'm using is scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2 with minit='matrix'

Comment: Could you specify the function you are passing the tuple of lists into? In itself, there is nothing wrong with declaring initPoints as you did.

Comment: Sounds like the function expects an object with a `shape` attribute, not just a plain tuple.

Comment: It sounds like you are using `numpy`. Is that right? If so, you should be aware that numpy's datatypes are _completely different_ from python's built-in types. Please edit your question to give some more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs to [`scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html) indicate, `k` should be a `numpy.ndarray` when you pass in `minit='matrix'`. So do this:

```
initPoints = numpy.array([[10,20,30],[5,15,25],[100,150,200]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the function is expecting a numpy array or matrix instead of a tuple of lists?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)
```

We'd need more information (like what you are passing this to) to know for sure.